# Line connector between two shapes using jquery -dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a toolbar that contains few shapes. Once I drag and drop the shapes from the toolbar to the drawing pane, I need to connect the shapes using simple lines dynamically. i.e, selected two shapes(only two) and connect it using a line.

Currently I am using clone and drag-drop feature of jquery. But I am unable to find a way to connect the cloned shapes. Any idea..?

FYI, I am cloning the shapes from toolbar to the drawing pane.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your sharps have a class item-1, item-2, item-3,..etc. So you can access them through this class, like this:

```
function getSharp(index){
  return $('.item-' + index);
}
```

Comment: As I said I am cloning the shapes. So how can I get identify them. My page will be looking like this  
jsfiddle.net/wJUHF/7